# Assign tags to the particular resource within CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to assign some tags to the particular resource in my `CloudFormation` template. Let's say, I want to do that for the `VPNGateway`. I do not see any specific form for that in the Template Designer, so, I guess, I should manually add an appropriate key-value inside JSON template description.

Let's say that template block for this `VPNGateway` looks like:

```
   "XXXXXX": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPNGateway",
            "Properties": {},
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "xxxxx-yyyy-zzzzz"
                }
            }
        }
```

Where I should place here tags information? For instance, I want to add tag with key "`test:key`" and value "`test:value`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done in the `Properties` block:

```
        "Properties": {
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "test:key",
                    "Value": "test:value"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Your self-answer beat my answer, but you can also look up the template for each resource type on AWS: [here's EC2 VPNGateway's](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpn-gateway.html)

Comment: Okay, it would be nice if you expand my answer with the additional info. I am sorry that I have beaten your one, I have just found this solution.